# TI LM4F120, GNU ARM GCC eabi and malloc: crash when calling malloc

Tags: c, embedded, malloc

I am working with the Stellaris Launchpad, [GCC arm embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.7/4.7-2012-q4-major) and I am trying to use malloc. According to [this](http://communities.mentor.com/community/cs/archives/arm-gnu/msg00995.html) it should not be a problem at all, but it is a problem at compile time: you need an implementation of _sbrk to make it run. So based on [this](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/stellaris_arm/f/471/t/44452.aspx#539503) thread I created the following _sbrk implementation:

```
#include "stdio.h"
extern int  _HEAP_START;
extern int  _HEAP_END;

extern void *_sbrk(int incr)
{
    static unsigned char *heap = NULL;
    unsigned char *prev_heap;

    if (heap == NULL) {
        heap = (unsigned char *)&_HEAP_START;
    }
    prev_heap = heap;

    if ((heap + incr) >= (unsigned char *)&_HEAP_END) {
        return 0;
    }
    heap += incr;
    return (void *)prev_heap;
}
```

I also have the following linkerscript to define a stack, a heap and all the rest (also based on the same thread)

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 256K
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    .data : AT (ADDR(.text) + SIZEOF(.text))
    {
        _data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
    } > SRAM

    .bss :
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
        . = ALIGN (8);
       _end = .;
    } > SRAM
}

/* end of allocated ram _end */
PROVIDE( _HEAP_START = _end );

/* end of the heap -> align 8 byte */
PROVIDE ( _HEAP_END = ALIGN(ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM) - 8 ,8) );
```

the last pieces of information: Compiler params:

```
-g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -DPART_LM4F120H5QR -c -Iinc/  -Ilib/inc -I/usr/arm-none-eabi/include -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1
```

And the Linker params:

```
-Tlib/linker_script.ld --entry ResetISR --gc-sections -L lib/ -L /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib -o final.elf obj/main.c.o obj/_sbrk.c.o obj/startup_gcc.c.o obj/switch.S.o -ldriver-cm4f -lc -lm
```

The main file consists of one malloc call:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(){
    int *i = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

And it crashes on the malloc call. Breakpoints in the _sbrk do not get hit, so the program crashes before it even reaches _sbrk. What is going on? Why does malloc not, as promised, work on its own? And why does it crash before it reaches its core algorithm (_sbrk)?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the source code to the library seems to be in the package you pointed to, so the easy way to get an answer might be to step through the `malloc()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found the mistake: I used the wrong libraries. For this version of the stellaris launchpad and GCC arm embedded 4.8 you need to use the Thumb libraries, which (on my pc) has the following directories:

/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb (for libM and libC (and libC++ etc))
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.3/thumb/ (for libgcc)